# Convert mp4 to webm in a reasonable time

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, webvideos

I have found [this solution](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/28276/38402) provided by [hackerb9](https://video.stackexchange.com/users/25965/hackerb9):

```
ffmpeg  -i input.mp4  -b:v 0  -crf 30  -pass 1  -an -f webm -y /dev/null
ffmpeg  -i input.mp4  -b:v 0  -crf 30  -pass 2  output.webm
```

It's works, but the second pass require more than 10 hours (for 30 minutes of video HD).

Now the question is: can I do the same things in a reasonable time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, consider to avoid "2-pass" if you only need to convert format.
Most of time, CRF is enough unless you have specific requirement on the output file size.

Use "CRF" to control on the quality and size. CRF lower means better quality.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:v 0 output.webm
```

There's parameter "-row-mt" for VP9 encoder to turn on "Row based multithreading" function, which enhances the number of encoder threads.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:v 0 -row-mt 1 output.webm
```

And there're some parameters for VP9 encoder to control on the quality/speed tradeoff. So in the "Two-Pass" case, you could try to use those parameter to get more speed by give-up some quality.

-deadline can be set to realtime, good, or best.

-cpu-used sets how efficient the compression will be.

**[Reference]**

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264 - "Two-Pass Section"

Comment: I have to say you thank you, even if you haven't completely solve my problem, with your script the result it's a file which before it's 1.5 GB, and now is 320 GB, with the same quality.

Answer (score 0):

To speed it up you need to increase the compute power and throughput of your computer. I think on my machine the I/O is the bottleneck, but yours may be different so look at upgrading any or all of the following:

- CPU - a faster processor allows for more operations per second
- Hard drive - running all video operations off a separate drive to your operating system is essential for speed. For even higher throughput, you can use a [RAID array](https://www.promax.com/blog/what-raid-is-best-for-video-editing) of drives
- Entire system - running multiple computers in parallel can, well, parallelise lengthy operations like this. This may be overkill for what you want

It may be simplest for you to just buy a new machine.

Comment: Thank you, I had considered several of these options. I have done the conversion by shutting down all other tasks and the Wi-Fi network. Regarding the 'Ferrari', I would say that it's all too easy an answer. :-)

Comment: I used to do work with cgi rendering, and the only way to do it in a sensible timeframe was to have multiple machines each with multiple processors, using a high speed RAID array. Video is not quite as computationally expensive, but it is a simple solution to get a better machine, if you have the budget